# How to fetch (poll) data periodically from an rss feed

Tags: php, xml, parsing, rss, polling

I have a rss feed (xml) that is updated frequently. I need to send  notifications to APNS if new update is avaliable on rss feed (xml). So far I know I can parse xml with php and send the result to APNS with my local Apache Server on Mac (MAMP).

But I do that by simply entering `php xxx.php` command on terminal window.The File `xxx.php` first parses the xml file and then sends the results to the APNS server.

My question is

**How can I periodically run this php file on a server?

Do I need a Virtual Private Server?

If so what is the code or function for running a php file continuously or every 10 mins ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cron` on a linux/mac server to run periodically any command (for example: `php xxx.php`)

I) In a command prompt you can edit the `crontab` with: `crontab -e`

II). At the end you add a line for every script you want to run periodically. Each line must follow this pattern:

```
`minute` `hour` `day of the month` `month` `day of the week` `command`
```

For example if you want to run the script every hour you add this line:

```
* */1 * * * php xxx.php
```

III) Then exit with `CTRL+X` and save.

More examples on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 3):

To run a file periodically you have to manage cron jobs, I wanted to describe what you have to do but I found a good profound article, It's worthy to have a look on it.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a *cron job*: See this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) entry.
Check to see if your host allows you to run cron jobs, and if not -- consider contacting them to see if they can set it up for you.